# federated login Vs. oauth on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, authentication

i would like to provide a third party user authentication on my app engine app. 
the federated login option on appengine is not exactly what I'm looking for and i can't see endpoints

what i want is authenticating users via openid like its done here on stackoverflow. 
the first time a user has to authorize the app and the subsequent times it will only need to be logged in or log in again on the third party app and then redirected to my app.

my app is written in python and im using tornado web as a framework. i've seen that tornado has its own auth module i want to check out but i wanted to ask for suggestions before jumping into code.

basically i would like users to be able to log in via facebook, twitter and google.

the facebook authentication seems not to be that hard on graph.facebook.com but its not easy to test
authenticating via twitter looks more difficult to me and i can't find any clear examples.

i would love to hear your experiences/suggestions about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is exactly how federated login with OpenId works on App Engine. Whether or not users get prompted for authorization after the first login is up to the OpenId provider, not the consumer.

Facebook login doesn't use OpenID, and you'd need to implement that yourself, in conjunction with a sessions library to keep track of logged in Facebook users.

Comment: @aschmid00 Twitter uses OAuth (it's really designed for authorization, not authentication, but people use it as auth anyway), which is supported by App Engine, just not as part of federated login.

Comment: @nick johnson thats what i mean. if i want to use google, facebook, twitter to authenticate users i can use the federated login only for the google account. which means its better if i use the tornado auth package which is kind of ported to work on appengine within the tipfy framework to have one package which deals with the authentication.

Comment: @aschmid00 You said in your question "what i want is authenticating users via openid like its done here on stackoverflow", so that's what I answered.

Comment: at the end i implemented the twitter and facebook login myself and I use federated login for google. thank you nick for your help.

Comment: @aschmid00 could you give some details, or links to places you reffered from? Thanks

Comment: @hamutsi: here how to implement the facebook login: https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py and for the twitter auth you could look at http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Writing-a-twitter-service-on-App-Engine